# How to insert items inside a callout control in expression blend 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, expression-blend-4, callout

I need a idea in inserting images and hyper link buttons inside a callout control which is used in Microsoft Expression Blend 4.

Please help me any idea to sort out this issue.

thanks,
Neon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sweat, like this.

```
<ed:Callout AnchorPoint="0,1.5" CalloutStyle="Cloud" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" Width="150">
    <ed:Callout.Content>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,20">
            <TextBlock Text="blah"/>
            <TextBlock Text="blah"/>
            <TextBlock Text="blah"/>
            <TextBlock Text="blah"/>
                        <Button Content="blah"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ed:Callout.Content>
</ed:Callout>
```

Cheers :)